# ERR_ABORTED 400 (BAD REQUEST) con javascript y python/flask

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask

Estoy tratando de consumir una API de flask pero me muestra el error

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/comprarLibro net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Mi codigo python es el siguiente,

```
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/comprarLibro', methods=['POST'])
def comprar_libro():
print('Entro python')
data_request = request.get_json()
print(data_request)
data = {}

try:
    data['exito'] = True
except Exception as e:
    data['mensaje'] = 'Error'
    data['exito'] = False
return jsonify(data)
```

Mi codigo JS es el siguiente

```
const csrf_token = document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").value;
const confirmarCompra = async () => {
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/comprarLibro', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'isbn': '5897463587'
        })
    }).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.error("Error");
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        console.log("Libro comprado");
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.error(`Error ${error}`);
    });
};
```

No tengo mucha experiencia con javascript, actualmente estoy tomando un curso de python pero veo que aqui utiliza js, ya busque recursos pero no logro encontrar como solucionar este problema

Comment: Tienes 2 errores, uno en el lado del servidor que es el uso del decorador `@login_required` Si estas utilizando `flask_wtf` entonces el comportamiento sería que no se acceda a esa ruta si no estas logeado. El segundo error es en el lado del cliente, el header correcto es `X-CSRFToken` (mira bien las mayúsculas y minúsculas)

Comment: Hice los cambios que me recomiendas pero sigue sin funcionar, también añadí el uso de CORS (porque entre algunas pruebas que he echo me apareció ese error), ahora me muestra un error de **SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**, ya revise y no me faltan cerrar ningún paréntesis o llave, voy a proceder editar mi código con los cambios hechos